# What is the recommended way to decorate request and response object with custom helpers in marblejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, marblejs

As the title of the question, what are the guidelines for decorating request and response object with custom data or helpers in marble.js or Node.js in general?

This situation arises when there is a middleware that wishes to inject or decorate request with additional data, ex. authorization middleware adding auth data or helper functions added by middleware to help with streaming large files.

As I currently understand, marblejs exposes `HTTPRequest` and `HTTPResponse` objects. They are simply extending native Node.js request and response object as:

```
export interface HttpRequest extends http.IncomingMessage {}
export interface HttpResponse extends http.ServerResponse {}
```